# NSURLConnection disable "too many HTTP redirects"

Tags: iphone, redirect, nsurlconnection

I am currently doing many server side computations that take a while to process.

In the mean time I redirect the user to the same page until it has a response.

This is resulting in a "too many HTTP redirects" error. Is there a way to disable this, or increase its threshold?

This happens on the simulator and on the phone.

here is the relevant code:

```
//Define request

NSURLRequest *request = [requestGenerator theRequest];



// Execute URL and read response

NSError *error = nil;

NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse;

NSData *resp = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&httpResponse error:&error];



 //If we get a good response

if(resp != nil && httpResponse != NULL && [httpResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [httpResponse statusCode] < 300)

{

   ... 

}



if (error) {

  [self  showErrorMessage:error];

}
```

Comment: If the page is not for display to an end user, then why keep redirecting? Couldn't you send a 200 from the server, and then render the rest of the response as and when it's ready?

Comment: Also, the approach you're suggesting generates unnecessary network traffic, which is best avoided on the iPhone, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting to the same URL is extremely wasteful.  At the very least, assign the "job" an ID and return that to the calling app.  It can then poll the server, passing up the ID, to see when the job completes.  You should not poll too frequently, perhaps once every few seconds.

You can also just use a single request-response.  Your server will simply not respond until it has the data.  On the iPhone the default time-out is set to 60 seconds.  Your server may be able to start a response (write out a little data) so the connection is established; but do not complete & close the connection until processing completes.

Finally, if you do a simply request ... long delay ... response; and expect it will take > 60 seconds - consider extending the timeout of the request via [NSMutableURLRequest's setTimeoutInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Note: in your example you are using a synchronous request.  If you do that outside of a thread, your app can block.  If it blocks for > 20 seconds, it will be killed by the watchdog service.  It's very easy to use the asynch methods with delegates to catch the responses, so give them a whirl.

Finally, if you use the asynch methods; you can catch the 3xx redirect and handle it yourself; but you know, your redirect technique seems evil so don't do it.

Comment: ps: if you return a 'job-id' then your server will need to persist the job result until the client calls back to fetch it.  You'll also need a clean-up task on the server that will prune jobs that are old and forgotten.